# Pointers in example

Tags: c, pointers

I've been struggling to get a firm understanding on pointers in c. I found an example that hopefully with some explanation will help me and others struggling understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>



void f2(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n", *a, *b, *c);
    *a = *b + *c;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", *a, *b, *c);

}


int main()
{
    int a, *b, c;

    a = 6;
    b = &c;
    c = 4;
    printf("a: %d %d %d\n", a, *b, c);
    a = 10;
    *b = 14;
    c = 16;
    printf("b: %d %d %d\n", a, *b, c);
    a = 6;
    b = &a;
    c = 4;
    f2(&c,b,&a);
    printf("f: %d %d %d\n", a, *b, c);
    return(0);
}
```

Here is the output

```
a: 6 4 4
b: 10 16 16
4 6 6
12 6 6
f: 6 6 12
```

Here are my questions as I have them.

1. Why is *b declared as an int but yet b is set equal to &c. What is b=&c doing in relation to declaring *b as an int.
2. In the chunk below *b is set equal to 14 but it still giving out the new value of c, why?
3. Finally, &c is passed through f2 as *a and its value changes even though f2 is a void function. Why does this happen as well?

Comment: Please format your questions so that they're legible.

Comment: it's not that `*b` is declared as an `int`, it's that `b` is declared as an `int *`; a pointer to an `int`.  `b=&c` passes in the address of `c` to `b` so `b`, which again, is a pointer to an `int`, is now pointing to `c`.  For any more than that, I recommend you consult a book on C programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is *b declared as an int but yet b is set equal to &c. What is b=&c doing in relation to declaring *b as an int.

The *expression* `*b` has type `int` - the *object* `b` is declared as a *pointer to* `int`; it stores the address of another `int` object.  The expression `&c` evaluates to the address of `c`.  Thus, you're storing the address of `c` into `b`.  When this is done, the following are true:

```
 b == &c // type pointer to int, both evaluate to address of c
*b ==  c // type int, both evaluate to value stored in c
```

Graphically, you have something like this:

```
                       +---+
                    a: |   |
   +---+               +---+
b: |   | ---------> c: |   |
   +---+               +---+
```

IOW, the *expressions* `b` and `&c` yield the address of `c`, while the expressions `*b` and `c` yield the value *stored in* `c`.

> n the chunk below *b is set equal to 14 but it still giving out the new value of c, why?

Remember that `*b` and `c` evaluate to the same thing, so writing `*b = 14` is equivalent to writing `c = 14`.  So basically, you write `14` to `c`, then *immediately* overwrite it with `16`.

> Finally, &c is passed through f2 as *a and its value changes even though f2 is a void function. Why does this happen as well?

Like the situation with `b`, the parameter `a` in your function *points to* `c`, so

```
 a == &c // type pointer to int, both evaluate to the address of c
*a ==  c // type int, both evaluate to the value stored in c
```

In the function, you assign a new value to `*a`.  Since `*a` is equivalent to `c`, it's the same as assigning the new value to `c`.  It has nothing to do with the function return type.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why is *b declared as an int but yet b is set equal to &c. What is b=&c doing in relation to declaring *b as an int

`b` is declared as an int pointer that can store  addresses of an int

By doing `b=&c`, you are giving `b` the memory address of the variable `c`. That is, consider that the variable `c` is allocated the memory address `1000H`, then that address is what is stored in the pointer `b`, and when we use `*b`, the value inside the address in `b` is shown. Whatever changes we make to `*b` is reflected in `c` and changes made in `c` are reflected in `*b`

> 2. In the chunk below *b is set equal to 14 but it still giving out the new value of c, why?

Well `b` is pointing to the address in `c`, so when value in `c` is changed, the value shown by `*b` also changes

> 3. Finally, &c is passed through f2 as *a and its value changes even though f2 is a void function. Why does this happen as well?

Address of `c` is passed over to `a` in the function. So whatever changes are made to the value of `*a` will be reflected in `c`

You might need to learn about pointers to understand more about this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why is `*b` declared as an `int`?

Well it is `b` which is declared as `int*` meaning it can hold address of an `int` variable. That explains why we can write `b=&c`. `&` is address of operator. If we put `&` before your house we will get your address. Well that means if we `&c` then it means we are getting the address of `int` variable named `c`.

#### In the chunk below `*b` is set equal to 14 but it still giving out the new value of `c`, why?

Because the order of it is like that. `*b=14`. It means go to the address that is in the variable `b` and make the content of that address to `14`. Then in the very next line you explicitly say to change the content of the variable whose address was in `b`. Well that's why you see the changed value.

#### Finally, `&c` is passed through `f2` as `*a` and its value changes even though `f2` is a void function. Why does this happen as well?

What goes with the name? Don't get the name confuse you.

```
    f2(&c,b,&a);

void f2(int *a, int *b, int *c)
```

`a` is a local variable - local to `f2` which got `c` (`main()`) variable's address. Same with `b` but this time it got the content of the `b` in main. `c` is same as the local variable `a` but it got address of `a` variable from `main()`.

Now you have all the addresses. By accessing it with `*` you make changes to the location that they point to. The copies (By copy `a`,`b` and `c` of `f2()` function is considered) are still there - they don't do anything other than to provide you the address of the variables that are in `main()`.

So well now you yourself can understand that a function being `void` doesn't have anything to do with making changes to some variables whose address has been passed to the function.